# Should I comment when calling a method?

Tags: java, javadoc, comments

I would like to know if I should comment before calling a method. For example:

```
//calling method
MethodCall();
```

or is it good enough with the javadoc commenting on the method header for example:

```
/**
some method 
*/
public static void() {
    Statements;
}
```

Which one should I use or should I use both?

Comment: `//calling method` and `MethodCall();` are basically identical. You shouldn't need both.

Comment: In my opinion you don't have to do the "calling method..."-thing. Your should give comments, when you explain some lines/parts of your code and not point out obvious things. A method header for javadoc is always a good thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of many reason of comment is to help otherss (and you) to understand what and mainly why you do what you do, but there is no need to write comment such as this:

```
// Loop through all bananas in the bunch
foreach(banana b in bunch) {
    monkey.eat(b);  //make the monkey eat one banana
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I see this an awful lot in production code, and a lot of the time I find myself wondering why some comments are even there. Remember *good code comments itself*.

**Example**

```
public void doSomething() { 
    // Some code
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Calling doSomething()
    doSomething();
}
```

It's clear from the code, that you're calling `doSomething`. Now if it isn't clear in the method name, what that method does (or why it is relevant) then by all means comment it:

```
// Calling doSomething() to establish a connection to the Database.
doSomething();
```

But then you've got to ask yourself, what makes more sense?

- Adding a comment
- Changing the method name so that it's instantly recognisable.

And it is most certainly the latter.

```
 public void establishDatabaseConnection() {
      // Some code
 }
```

Makes a hell of a lot more sense.

**Summary**

For me, the guide for comments is simple:

> If it isn't *explicitly clear*, why you're calling a method in a given context, then first check the name of that method. If that name could be changed to add clarity, then change it. If the name is as clear as possible, and your code is simply complex, then you can add a comment.

Answer (score 6):

What benefit could you possibly gain from commenting `//calling method` when you're calling a method?
Whoever is reading your code will see it on the next line anyway.

Use javadoc comments to document the method and its parameters their purpose.

Comments should explain *why* you're doing something, not *what*.

Comment: Thanks for the little lecture cuz I really need it since I saw at commenting so much lol. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Please don't comment when calling a method, just call the method. Unless there is a very specific reason to comment it like "// TODO remove this method call after bug xyz is fix"

This is very useless commenting:

```
// add 1 to i
i = i + 1;
```

Try to realize that you code in code and not in comments so make your code as clear as possible. Comments can easily get old/out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Many good comments focus on *why* you're doing something, rather than what you're doing; the what should be obvious from the code. There are some cases (often with string munging) where the what isn't obvious, in which case the comment should describe what's happening in human terms, often by citing an example.

A significant counter-example is when a method implements a somewhat tricky algorithm. In that case, it's good to have a comment block describe (again, in human terms) the outline of what's happening. But in that case, you're not "micro-commenting" line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the method you're calling has confusing and cryptic parameters.

There are other instances when the order you're calling methods is very important, and shouldn't be move around. This is sometimes useful to document because sometimes people get clever and try to fix code that ain't broke.

Answer (score 0):

Method header javadoc commenting is always a good idea.  So for most function calls, that is enough, but sometimes you will want to add a comment where you are calling it, too.  When you call a method with some default (magic!) numbers is a great place to add a comment, explaining why you used the magic number you used.

For example, given the following function

```
/**This function takes the following arguments.... */
public int foo(int a, int b){//does stuff}
```

I would not bother to comment the call if I had two inputs (first and second) like so:

```
foo(first, second);
```

But in the case where I only had first, and want to use the default 42, I would comment:

```
//the default is 42, because it is the answer to life, the universe, and everything.
foo(first, 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, this varies greatly, depending on your code.

I generally like well-documented code, especially the one used in your second example - but not when the method itself is self explanatory.

Imagine a Point class declaring an x and y variable and 2 getters and setters (e.g. getX, setX). There is not really any need to comment what this class does or describe its intented use - it is pretty obvious.

You should strive to make the code readable - if you need to use comments it is generally a sign that your code is not easy to read or understand, so consider changing your code before commenting it.

If you code can still be hard to understand after making it more reasonable, then use method documentation like your second example to explain the purpose of the method, its input and its output.

Only use INLINE comments if it is absolutely necessary to understand some important workings of your code that is almost impossible to guess, and is important for someone else to understand, and does not fit in the method documentation - or use them to mark things that you still ned to do or handle in your method like "Remember to check if user is logged in before fetching data". This way when you look through your code you can see your comments and remember what you need to still do.

Personally I use inline comments to describe a method initially without code e.g.

```
public double divideNumbers(double top, double bottom){
    //Check bottom is different from zero and throw exception if zero
    //Divide top with bottom
    //Return result
}
```

This way I can take a comment one by one, implement it, and then continue to the next comment.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will only add to code clutter. What is the reason for duplication? What if the method is renamed? You'll have to update the comments, which is double work.

```
//calling method
MethodCall();
```